# Unobvious usage of articles "The" and "A"

Tags: grammaticality, articles, determiners

Some examples needing an explanation, thank you for the help.

1. "I came up with **(an)** idea, we can do..." We should use "an", shouldn't we? But why, if we have a specific idea explained further? What about "He gave me a/the idea to admit to the university" then?
2. "**The** conclusion is ..." Why should we use "the", when it's the first mention of the conclusion. Maybe because that conclusion is specific, only for that situation. Then should i use "the" in the next sentence "I came up with **the** conclusion. The conclusion is..."?
3. "I have **a/the** feeling i don't love him". "The" because i tell what specific feeling i have further?
4. "I am gonna watch **a/the** video". What if only i know that video, and i want to watch a specific video, but another person in a dialogue doesn't know that video.

Comment: Here is where rules break down. Say "I am gonna watch **a** video" to announce your plans. It doesn't matter that inside you know that specific video, because your listener does not and you haven't gone into which video.

Comment: Telling the OP to 'update the question so it focuses on one problem only [as] this will help others answer the question', seems counterproductive in view of the fact that the question has already received a reasonable answer. The OP could post this as four separate questions, but this would only only add to the unnecessary clutter on the site. The underlying idea behind the four subquestions is fairly clear: these are all cases in which the standard textbook rules are applied in the ways that are not immediately obvious.

Comment: I found a dog. It was a golden retriever and answered to Bruce.

Comment: All usages of articles _the_ and _a_ are unobvious. They have no meaning, but they participate in hundreds of idioms and constructions where they sometime oppose and sometimes are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *I came up with an idea: we can have a pancake-making contest.*

This is correct because the idea is unspecified until one gets to the second independent clause. But

- *I came up with the idea of having a pancake-making contest.*

needs the definite article because the idea is (immediately) post-specified by the prepositional string.

........

- *the conclusion* because it's the only one [considered] available.

........

- *I have a/the feeling that she doesn't love him*. [sounds more reasonable]

Either is idiomatic here, as [these Google 5-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+feeling+that+she%2Chave+the+feeling+that+she&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) strongly suggest:

[image]

[image]

and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-get-a-the-feeling-that) endorses:

> **have​/​get a​/​the feeling (that)** [phrase] ...
>
> to be conscious of something but not certain about it
>
> - *I have a feeling we’ve met before.*
> - *I had the feeling she was watching me.*

........

- *I'm gonna watch a/the video*.

If the video is a particular one and has been mentioned already or is in some other way in the addressee's mind, 'the' ... otherwise 'a'.

Comment: _A_ conclusion is that you should share the details of _the_ pancake-making contest with us. Where do I sign up?

Comment: I've just been watching Salem. I mean _Sabrina_.

Comment: This explains clearly the cases **1**, **2**, and **4**, but for **3** effectively say just 'that's how it is'. That is, however, precisely the case that is the most in need of an explanation: **why** are both possibilities idiomatic, and is there a subtle difference in meaning between them?

Comment: I'd say that's as far as one can go without guesswork, jsw. 'Have a suspicion that' sounds more natural than 'have the suspicion that' to me, as one can have varied suspicions ... but the latter seems the more common. Perhaps 'have the idea that' suggests a more strongly held belief than 'have an idea that'. 'Have the inkling that' is relatively uncommon. Perhaps 'the' refers to a commonly experienced, well known state, as perhaps in 'have the flu', 'have the urge to'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth your examples with the? flu are helpful

Comment: ... But we don't say "I have the cold" ... arguably commoner. And "I have the flu" is rather dated, at least in the NW of England; normally, we'd drop the article. This suggests that styles change, and article usage is somewhat idiosyncratic.